# Bug with Bounty Emails

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounty

I keep getting emails to select an answer on my bounty question, despite having selected one. I got today the following email: "Your bounty on question "Package does not exist error when package was added to classpath" has expired - answer auto-selected." I checked and the answer I selected is still selected.

Just reporting the bug.

Comment: Users that accept an answer but don't award the bounty just make it hard for everybody else with a bounty on their question to get an answer.  Bad form.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes! That is terrible! Good thing there is auto-answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You actually hadn't awarded the bounty - all you had done was marked an answer as accepted. Fortunately when you mark an answer as accepted, we assume that you wanted to award the bounty to that answer too and automatically select that answer for the full bounty amount when the bounty expires.

It *was* auto-selected for you, but based on a selection you had made previously.